# Webpack configuration for react and django app

Tags: python, reactjs, django, webpack

I am planning to make a boilerplate in GitHub between React and Django  To facilitate me later When I start a project

**I chose the connection method React as Django app**

```
django-admin startapp frontend
```

The problem I am facing now is that I am using the Django templates. **I cannot split packages using wepback because there must be {load static} {static ''index.js"}**

However, I cannot use Splitchuncks in configuring a webpack or HTML plugin to insert script tags into HTML. The entire code must be inside one js file and that too with CSS

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
// const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./static/frontend"),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },

      {
        test: /\.css$/,

        use: [
          devMode ? "style-loader" : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          "postcss-loader",
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3|svg|ico)$/,
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          outputPath: path.resolve(__dirname, "./static/images"),
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    // splitChunks: {
    //   chunks: 'all',
    //   name: false,
    // },
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
      Object.assign(
        {},
        {
          inject: true,
          template: "./templates/frontend/index.html",
        },
        devMode
          ? undefined
          : {
              minify: {
                removeComments: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                useShortDoctype: true,
                removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                keepClosingSlash: true,
                minifyJS: true,
                minifyCSS: true,
                minifyURLs: true,
              },
            }
      )
    ),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        // This has effect on the react lib size:::: Note Change to production in production build
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("development"),
      },
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css",
      chunkFilename: "static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.css",
    }),
  ],
};
```

**Should I ever think about changing the connection method? Or not there is a problem using one file that carries the entire code**

---

**Any advice on changing the method of communication or any article on communication methods react inside django is very welcome**

Comment: Good Django+React boilerplate https://github.com/saasitive/django-react-boilerplate with a lot of explanations

Comment: @pplonski Really cool work, but that's a question. I've read a lot that I should stop using the create-react-app. It adds some third-party libraries that are not important in production, and have complete control over the project. Should I be concerned about this or should I go ahead and use this project?

Comment: It depends on the project. But I prefer to separate frontend and backend. No dependencies between them.